# When submit a form, check if if textbox is a certain string and show alert based on answer

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textbox

My form has the code

```
<form class="form" name="frmName" onclick="javascript:check()">
Answer: <input type="text" name="textboxans">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

And when the user clicks on the submit button, I want to run a script such that if the user typed in 15 in the answer textbox, the user is greeted with an alert but another message if not. This is the code I have which is placed in the head of my HTML document.

```
<script>
function check()
var ans="15";
if (document.forms["frmName"]["textboxans"].value==ans){
alert("That is the correct answer");
}
else{
alert("Sorry. That is the incorrect answer");
}
</script>
```

I'm still getting issues that when I press the submit button, nothing is happening. Can anyone help?

Comment: use onSubmit() in form tag

Comment: your function check doesnt have opening and closing braces. Make sure you put it.

Answer (score 2):

The `onsubmit` event occurs when the submit button in a form is clicked.

`<form class="form" name="frmName" onsubmit="javascript:check()">`

Comment: I changed it to onsubmit but it is still not working. Could it be that my Javascript is wrong? Edit: I added the opening and closing braces to my function and it is working now. Thank you.

Comment: Good job! You might notice that no matter what, the form is still going to post to the page.  You might want to change the onSubmit to return either true or false (eg. `onSubmit="return check()"`).  Then add to your conditions a return of true or false:  `alert("correct"); return true;` and `alert("no no no"); return false;`

Answer (score 0):

use onSubmit()

```
<form class="form" name="frmName" onSubmit="javascript:check()">
Answer: <input type="text" name="textboxans">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this this will help you

```
var ans="15";
$('form').click(function(){
if ($('input[type=text]').val()==ans){
alert("That is the correct answer");
}
else{
alert("Sorry. That is the incorrect answer");
}
});
```

Fiddle [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/MRxTA/2/)

you are missing `{` after function check() and input tag also not closed properly `/>`, please involve it